# Pun (Photon) Unity 5 Player list Returning only local

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

baically when i call this it only shows my players name and not the others but when i change the foreach loop to foreach(PhotonPlayer player in PhotonNetwork.otherPlayers) it then returns the other player so where could i be going wrong?

this was the loop that shows that shows me only

```
void openCloseScore(){
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Tab)) {
        ScoreBoard.SetActive (true);
        foreach(PhotonPlayer player in PhotonNetwork.playerList) {
            ScoreboardTxt.text = "\r\nPlayerName:  " + player.ToString
                ();
        }
    } else {
        ScoreBoard.SetActive (false);
    }
   }
```

this one shows other players. this is how i know the script above should be getting all the players.

```
void openCloseScore(){
    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Tab)) {
        ScoreBoard.SetActive (true);
        foreach(PhotonPlayer player in PhotonNetwork.otherPlayers) {
            ScoreboardTxt.text = "\r\nPlayerName:  " + player.ToString
                ();
        }
    } else {
        ScoreBoard.SetActive (false);
    }
   }
```

i need the loop to show everyone.

Comment: you are describing two different outputs. can you share the code for the alternative output?

Comment: What is the client state when you iterate player lists? These lists make sense only when client is joined to a room. They should return local player only in other cases.